# Error in deploying app onto domain for IBM Bluemix

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-discovery

I have been working on a chatbot which involves incorporating Watson Discovery and Watson Assistant. Precisely I have been using this link to help me: https://www.edx.org/course/programming-chatbots-with-watson-services

I have acquired the credentials and for this I use username:"apikey", password:"API_KEY_VALUE" (the actual value i get), and I used the other IDs as normal such as workspaceID, collectionID, environmentID.

I have managed to deploy the app to a domain before, this was before following the instructions in the course (Lab 3.3) when I have to copy and paste the code in the app.js. I have found a github link which is the same thing but it already has the code copied and so i copied the app.js into my own directory so as to save time and mistakes: https://github.com/odrodrig/hotelReviews

However when I try to deploy the app to a domain using ibmcloud cf push, I get the error as shown in the log of the image attached:

[image]

Log of app deployment

The code I use for app.js is the exact same as the one in the github link.

Comment: What is this Dynatrace? Where is it in the code you are pointing to?

Comment: Im not too sure, I tried looking in the code but could not find it